# How to fix, "Uncaught Error Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options."

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

https://github.com/techaddict0x/liquidityminer , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSdogDo2YF4

Hey people, I've been trying to clone this liquidity mining project, following the tutorial, but I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught Error Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.`

I'm using the same code as in the github link, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For future reference to better help people understand your issues, please try to include the code and any relevant information needed to help answer your question, without having to click on external links. Furthermore, the GitHub link contains multiple different languages and files so that doesn't help us narrow down where you are encountering your error at. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I’m fairly new to all of this web3 and js etc, I wouldn’t know where to start I thought I could watch the tutorial and follow step by step

Comment: I recommend you to read some of the solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/ as well as solidity-by-example: https://solidity-by-example.org/, and if you really want a video tutorial then definitely check out Patrick Collins: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umepbfKp5rI. He also has one based in Javascript (hardhat), and one in Python (brownie) if you have a preference/any previous experience with either of those.

Comment: take care of scams. many of these videos are scam and have hidden functions to get your ether